# Swift: Get an index of beginning and ending character of a word in a String

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsstring

A string:

`"jim@domain.com, bill@domain.com, chad@domain.com, tom@domain.com"`

Through gesture recognizer, I am able to get the character the user tapped on (happy to provide code, but don't see the relevance at this point).

Let's say the User tapped on `o` in `"chad@domain.com"` and the character `index` is `39`

Given `39` the `index` of `o`,  I would like to get the string start index of `c` where `"chad@domain.com"` begins, and an end `index` for `m` from `"com"` where `"chad@domain.com"` ends.

In another words, given an `index` of a `character` in a `String`, I need to get the `index` on the `left` and `right` right before we encounter a space in a `String` on the left and a `comma` on the right.

Tried, but this only provides the last word in the String:

```
if let range = text.range(of: " ", options: .backwards) {
  let suffix = String(text.suffix(from: range.upperBound)) 
  print(suffix) // tom@domain.com
}
```

I am not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `range(of:)` on two slices of the given string:
`text[..<index]` is the text preceding the given character position, 
and `text[index...]` is the text starting at the given position.

Example:

```
let text = "jim@domain.com, bill@domain.com, chad@domain.com, tom@domain.com"
let index = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: 39)

// Search the space before the given position:
let start = text[..<index].range(of: " ", options: .backwards)?.upperBound ?? text.startIndex

// Search the comma after the given position: 
let end = text[index...].range(of: ",")?.lowerBound ?? text.endIndex

print(text[start..<end]) // chad@domain.com
```

Both `range(of:)` calls return `nil` if no space (or comma) has
been found. In that case the nil-coalescing operator `??` is used
to get the start (or end) index instead.

(Note that this works because `Substring`s share a common index
with their originating string.)

---

An alternative approach is to use a "data detector",
so that the URL detection does not depend on certain separators.

Example (compare [How to detect a URL in a String using NSDataDetector](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-detect-a-url-in-a-string-using-nsdatadetector)):

```
let text = "jim@domain.com, bill@domain.com, chad@domain.com, tom@domain.com"
let index = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: 39)

let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))

for match in matches {
    if let range = Range(match.range, in: text), range.contains(index) {
        print(text[range])
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is more efficient.

Comment: @vadian: Thank you.

Comment: One more question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562781/swift-rect-for-text-inside-uitextview  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Different approach:

You have the string and the `Int` index

```
let string = "jim@domain.com, bill@domain.com, chad@domain.com, tom@domain.com"
let characterIndex = 39
```

Get the `String.Index` from the `Int`

```
let stringIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: characterIndex)
```

Convert the string into an array of addresses

```
let addresses = string.components(separatedBy: ", ")
```

Map the addresses to their ranges (`Range<String.Index>`) in the string

```
let ranges = addresses.map{string.range(of: $0)!}
```

Get the (`Int`) index of the range which contains `stringIndex`

```
if let index = ranges.index(where: {$0.contains(stringIndex)}) {
```

Get the corresponding address

```
let address = addresses[index] }
```

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon.  When I change character index to 4 or 50, both of these return "tom@domain.com":

Comment: The code in the answer works as described, maybe the kind of the source (the string and the index) are different.

Comment: PS: I recommend to use Martin's solution. It's better.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to split the original string on the “,” and then using simple math to find in what element of the array the given position (39) exist and from there get the right string or indexes for the previous space and next comma depending on what your end goal is.